# Show empty textbox to accept values in windows application

Tags: .net, vb.net

Want to add empty textbox in every row of DataGridView in windows application in VB to accept input value along with data binding using collection.

```vb
Private Sub CreateTableStyle()
    With grdViewer
        Dim colDesc As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        With colDesc

            .DataPropertyName = "Description"
            .HeaderText = "Description"
            '.Width = 350
            .ReadOnly = True
            .HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter

            .DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopLeft
            .DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
            .Name = "colDescription"
            .Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.True
            .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None
        End With
        .Columns.Add(colDesc)

        Dim colAssigned As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
        With colAssigned
            .DataPropertyName = "Assigned"
            .HeaderText = "Assigned"
            .HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            '.Width = 5
            .ReadOnly = True
            .DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Name = "colAssigned"
            .Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.True
            .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None
        End With
        .Columns.Add(colAssigned)

      Dim emptyTextColumn As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
        With emptyTextColumn
            .HeaderText = "Enter Description"
            .HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            '.Width = 5
            .ReadOnly = False
            .DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Name = "emptyTextColumn"
            .Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.True
            .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None
        End With
        .Columns.Add(emptyTextColumn)
        
     .DataSource = collectionPM

    End With

End Sub
```

Binding the data to this DataGridView from database and also want to add textbox in every row of DataGridView as separate column to accept user input for every row.

Comment: If you already retrieve and bind the other columns from your database, why can't you simply bind that column as well and just make it editable?

Comment: can you show the `collectionPM` object? Does the item-type in it have the Property `Description` ?

Comment: Add the additional columns **after** `.DataSource = collectionPM`. You should consider the first comment.

Comment: If you already have these fields in `collectionPM` and you  just need to modify the column's style as the `CreateTableStyle` suggests. Set `.DataSource = collectionPM` first, replace `Dim colDesc As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` with `Dim colDesc As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn = grdViewer.Columns("Description")` and do the rest except `.DataPropertyName = "Description"`, Do the same for the other column(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add another column to your code and not set its `DataPropertyName` property. It doesn't matter whether you do it before or after setting the `DataSource`. Personally, I would suggest that you get rid of that code and create the columns in the designer, unless there's a specific reason that you can't.

Comment: I have added another column with empty datagridviewtextboxcolumn value but not able to edit or write to the empty column.

Comment: @GaneshGholap, then you did it wrong. If you don't show us what you did, we can't tell what's wrong with it.

Comment: @GaneshGholap Don't set `DataPropertyName` if that field does not exist in `collectionPM`, If this is the case, add the column after setting the `.DataSource` property as I mentioned above.  And as mentioned, you don't need to do this if `collectionPM` already contains the `Description` and `Assigned` fields. Edit you question to show the `collectionPM` object as requested above.